# Replace whole string which contains substring in whole dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace all strings that contain a specific substring. So for example if I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['abc', 'abc123', 'abc456'], 
               'col_2': ['abc123', '123', 'abc456']})
```

I'd like to replace the string,which contains `'abc123'`, with the string 'test' like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['abc', 'test', 'abc456'], 
               'col_2': ['test', '123', 'abc456']})
```

I have tried:

```
df.loc[df['col_1'].str.contains('abc123',na=False), 'col_1'] = 'test'
```

But it can only process one col per time, I got hundreds of col to deal with. How could I make it in one time.

Comment: `df.mask(df.eq('abc123'),'test')` ?

Comment: You mention "substring" but your example doesn't clarify this. Should `zzabc123zz` also become `test`?

Comment: `eq` will change it the value equals to `abc123` not if values contains `abc123`. @anky_91
So if you just need to change substring and not all value you can use `df = df.replace('abc123', 'test', regex=True)` @Evan Chen

Comment: @talatccan right, i commented as per the input example :) hence a comment

Comment: You are right. My example doesn't clarify the question. 'zzabc123zz' 、 'qq11abc123/123'  should also be replaced by 'test'. @DeepSpace

Comment: @Evan.Chen in that case my answer will work as you expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that I changed the example to contain `zzabc123zz` since you mention "substring" in your question but the example you provided did not show that usecase.

You can use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a regex.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['abc', 'abc123', 'abc456'],
                   'col_2': ['abc123', '123', 'zzabc123zz']})

df.replace(re.compile('.*abc123.*'), 'test', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
    col_1  col_2
0     abc   test
1    test    123
2  abc456   test
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `str.contains` which [`selects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) the object dtypes from the df and [`stacks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the columns to do a str contains, finally [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m=df.select_dtypes('O')
df[m.columns]=m.mask(m.stack(dropna=False).str.contains('abc123',na=False).unstack(),'test')
print(df)
```

---

```
    col_1   col_2
0     abc    test
1    test     123
2  abc456  abc456
```